# Sharepoint Timerjobs running on wrong Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

we are facing the problem, that our custom timerjobs are running on the "wrong" servers in the farm.

In our case, the jobs are running on our crawl servers but the solution is only deployed on front end and application servers so we're getting the following error message in the uls log:
The type XXXX, XXXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXX could not be found in its specified assembly.  Scanning all assemblies that have been loaded in the current app domain.

Our topology: 2 Frontend Servers, 2 Application Servers, 2 Crawl Servers

Does anyone know this issue?

Thanks in advance